# libgdx moving to a more object oriented approach

Tags: arrays, oop, libgdx

So i am new to libgdx and have recently been following tutorials and forums online to create a basic game to really learn what libgdx is capable of.
to start with i followed the drop tutorial found here https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/A-simple-game

i have since played around and changed the whole aspect of the game and have reached a point where i wish to change how the objects are created and drawn from an array of rectangles to a more object oriented approach so they not only have rectangles for collisions but so i can also easily apply and update variables for game objects such as health.

the drop tutorial creates drops with an array of rectangles,
the commented out code with // is how the drop tutorial handled spawning drops and the following code is how ive been trying to convert that to an array of Enemy' objects.

```
 // Array<Rectangle> enemies;
    Array<Enemy> enemies;

alienImage = new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("enemies/alien.png")));

  // enemies = new Array<Rectangle>();
    enemies = new Array<Enemy>();
```

this method was called to create a new rectangle for a drop or in my case an enemy. however here i now want to create an instance of an enemy from my enemy class

```
private void spawnEnemy() {

   // Rectangle enemy = new Rectangle();
   // enemy.x = MathUtils.random(0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - 64);
  //  enemy.y = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
  //  enemy.setSize(32, 34);
   // enemies.add(enemy);

    Rectangle enemy = new Rectangle();
```

// maxhhealth , current health, center x , center y, width , height, rectangle

```
enemies.add(new Enemy(30,30,300,200,32,34,enemy ));

    lastEnemyTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
}
```

// here during the render method is where the drops are drawn using the rectangle array of drops. but now im trying to do the same for the array of enemy objects.

```
    for(Enemy enemy : enemies) {
        game.batch.draw(alienImage, enemy.getenemyX(), enemy.getenemyY(), enemy.getWidth(),enemy.getHeight());
    }

    //for (Rectangle enemy : enemies) {
    //    game.batch.draw(alienImage, enemy.x, enemy.y, enemy.getWidth(),enemy.getHeight());
    //}
```

//// this is my enemy class that i am trying to create an instance of, it has basic variables and some getters and setters.

```
public class Enemy {
float enemyX;
static float enemyY;
int width , height, health , maxhealth;
Rectangle enemy = new Rectangle();

public Enemy(int maxHealth, int health, int enemyX, int enemyY, int width , int height, Rectangle enemy) {
    setenemyX(enemyX);
    setenemyY(enemyY);
    setMaxHealth(maxHealth);
    sethealth(health);
    enemy.x = enemyX;
    enemy.y = enemyY;
    enemy.width = width;
    enemy.height = height;

}

public Rectangle getRect(){
    return enemy;
}

public int getWidth() {
    return width;
}

public int getHeight() {
    return height;
}


public int getMaxHealth() {
    return maxhealth;
}

public int getHealth() {
    return health;
}

public float getenemyX() {
    return enemyX;
}

public float getenemyY() {
    return enemyY;
}

public void setMaxHealth(int maxhealth) {
    this.maxhealth = maxhealth;
}

public void sethealth(int health) {
    this.health = health;
}

public void setenemyX(float enemyX) {
    this.enemyX = enemyX;
}

public void setenemyY(float enemyY) {
    this.enemyY = enemyY;
}


}
```

Overall When i run this code my program runs fine, but since trying to move from an array of rectangle to an array of enemy objects the 'enemies' are no longer being drawn. to test this i centered the first enemy in the middle of the screen and to make sure they weren't just off screen and not moving.

Ultimately i think ive implemented the almost exact same approach to drawing and moving the 'enemy' objects as the original rectangle approach, but being new to libgdx im missing something and im really stuck as to what it is.

with the lack of any errors and the game still running fine i cant help but think im close however, long story short my question is have i taken the right approach to making the drop game more objected oriented and am i simply missing something, or is there a much better way of handling and creating objects in libgdx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem most likely has to do with you using redundant variables and accessing one or the other at different moments.

Your Enemy class has variables for x, y, width and height, but it also has a variable for a rectangle, which has its own x, y, width and height.

Your Enemy constructor sets the inital size on the rectangle, but the getWidth and getHeight methods refer to the non-rectangle versions of these, which will still be zero, so you're drawing zero-sized sprites.

You either need to remove the rectangle or remove the position and size variables.

If you remove the rectangle, make sure you also remove the `static` keyword on your `enemyY` variable!

Edit:
Alternate solution that preserves Rectangle functionality:

```
public class Enemy extends Rectangle {
    int health, maxHealth;

    public Enemy (float x, float y, float width, float height, int health, int maxHealth) {
        super(x, y, width, height);
        this.health = health;
        this.maxHealth = maxHealth;
    }

}
```

Comment: i followed your lead and made sure the right height and width was being called and now the sprites draw, and after removing the static keyword the y are now back to moving normally :).

however now im having an issue where the rectangle collision is not working properly as it was before.
during the render process i have a small loop that goes through the array of enemies.
 i have a conditional statement  if (enemy.getRect().overlaps(player))
to detect a collision however it doesnt seem to be running. any thoughts at what im missing?

Comment: If you want to take advantage of the `overlaps` method of rectangle, then you could do the opposite of what you did...remove the four variables and use the rectangle instead. Or you could create your own `overlaps` method for your Enemy class. Or best yet, remove those four variables **and** the rectangle, and make your Enemy extend Rectangle. And make Player extend Rectangle as well. Then you can continue to use `overlaps` with them as you are now.

Comment: hmm okay thank you, It sounds like extending rectangle would be the best way to go. im a little lost now at what my enemy class should contain. could you give a quick example

Comment: if i understand correctly are you saying my enemy class should no longer contain an x , y width or height

so at its basic form it can be
public class Enemy extends Rectangle {

    public Enemy(int maxHealth, int health) {


    }

}

Comment: is this more what you mean?

public class Enemy extends Rectangle {

    float x;
    float y;
    int width;
    int height;
    int maxhealth;
    int health;

    public Enemy(int maxHealth, int health, float x, float y, int width , int height) {
        this.y = y;
        this.x = x;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }
}

Comment: Yes, except remove the declarations of width, height, x, and y. Those would *hide* the superclass variables with the same names, creating big problems.

Comment: you've been really helpful thank you. can i ask what is the difference between using  super(x, y, width, height);  and using this.x = x etc?

Comment: It's good OOP practice to rely on a superclass constructor in case there are side effects to setting the variables or necessary setup tasks for the class. Although in this case the Rectangle class is very simple and has no side effects, so it would be hard to mess up.

Comment: Hello thank you for your help yesterday, i have been doing some experimenting and was wondering if there was a way to map the same approach but extend actor instead of rectangle. simply for the ability to be able to add listeners and do fun things like rotate and scale actors

Comment: You could create write your own `overlaps` method for your own subclass of Actor. You'd have to figure out the calculation for yourself.